# Why won't my Font Awesome work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons

I've tried everything but still the icon doesn't show.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> icon-camera-retro
</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't work :(

Comment: Does the console say anything informative, or anything at all? Also, how are you loading this file? If you're loading this from the file system (using the `file://` protocol) then access to those resources referenced with a double-forward slash prefix will not work,

Comment: Are the addresses resolvable?  Telling us you have "Trying everything" doesn't leave us many things to try differently than what you've already tried.

Comment: has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Add `http:` to the beginning of the url

```
href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"
```

If you were developing this using a web server, your code would work. It's assumed that you're not and are using a local environment, and therefore you should add the `http:`

For more info, see [this post](http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/)

Comment: That should not be necessary, unless he's on `file://`.  He's using a protocol-relative URL.

Comment: Agreed, but it's likely that he is on `file://`. The links were copied directly from the font-awesome site, so that's the only logical conclusion unless the asker tells us otherwise